# Determine column value according to other columns in the same table

Tags: sql-server

I want to determine column value  for each row according to other columns in same table.

For example I have this table:

```
BbName 
DBStatus (online , offline , suspect.. etc) 
IsAutoClose (0 , 1)
IsAutoCreateStatistics (0 , 1)
IsAutoShrink (0 , 1) 
CheckDate (datetime)
Status(0 , 1)
```

Once in a month I insert data into these columns (`DbName, DBStatus, IsAutoClose, IsAutoCreateStatistics, IsAutoShrink, CheckDate`)

I want to determine  the status column value for each new row according to the other columns in that row.

Something like this

```
(IF DBStatus IN (offline, suspect) OR 
 IF IsAutoClose = 1 OR
 IF IsAutoCreateStatistics = 0) THEN 
    set Status = 1 
ELSE 
    set Status = 0
```

What is best way to that?

After insert trigger ?

Comment: I would just run a simple stored procedure over the table once the monthly data load is completed, to update the `Status` column

Comment: Afert the insert `Status` is null. 
Then I'll update with SP but I need to update some of the rows the 0 value and some of them to 1 value. 
How I do that in the update statement ?

Answer (score 1):

You could just run an `UPDATE` statement after the insert is done that updates your column `Status` - something like this:

```
-- update all rows with Status IS NULL to 1, if one of those 
-- given conditions is met
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Status = 1
WHERE Status IS NULL     -- update those that have no value yet
  AND (DBStatus IN (offline, suspect) 
       OR IsAutoClose = 1 
       OR IsAutoCreateStatistics = 0) 

-- now update all remaining rows with Status IS NULL to 0
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Status = 0
WHERE Status IS NULL     -- update those that have no value yet
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do in in one update query then try this:

```
update Yourtable
Set Status = CASE WHEN ( DBStatus IN (offline, suspect) OR 
             IsAutoClose = 1 OR
            IsAutoCreateStatistics = 0) THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
        END
WHERE (...Your condition for which you want data updated...)
```

Answer (score 0):

change status into a calculated column

```
alter table  temp 
add status as 
  case when DBStatus IN ('offline', 'suspect') then 1
       when IsAutoClose = 1                    then 1
       when IsAutoCreateStatistics = 0         then 1
       ELSE 0 
  end;
```

or you create a view on top of the table with a status column with that formula

Answer (score 0):

Just add a computed column:

```
alter table thistable
    add status as (case when DBStatus IN (offline, suspect) OR 
                             IsAutoClose = 1 OR
                             IsAutoCreateStatistics = 0
                        then 1 else 0
                   end) ;
```

It will be calculated on-the-fly, so it is always up-to-date.